# Alternative procedures when Box-Tidwell fails

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation

Minimal working example in R -- `car::boxTidwell` fails on the following dataset:

```
> library(car)
> x <- seq(270, 275, length.out = 100)
> y <- log(x) + rnorm(length(x))
> boxTidwell(y ~ x)
Error in lm.fit(cbind(1, x.log.x, x1.p, x2), y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

This can happen if there is multicollinearity between columns of `x.log.x`, `x1.p`, `x2` which causes wild estimates of `lambda` and the algorithm to diverge.

Note that `x` will be a matrix in the multivariate case.

Is there an alternative statistical procedure which can be used instead?

Comment: An extended account of classical EDA methods to identify Box-Cox transformations of the regressors (and of the response) is available on my recent course Web at http://www.quantdec.com/misc/MAT8406/Meeting07/Diagnostic_Plots.pdf .

Comment: Isn't box-tidwell ancient technology?  I would probably use a splien model for the regressor.